# Javascript only execute the last function called

Tags: javascript

I want my page to execute the same function 3 times, calling for 3 different things each time.

The code is currently

```
 <script>
 ajaxGet('/goget.php?name='+edit.dep.value, 'dep_result');
 ajaxGet('/goget.php?name='+edit.arr.value, 'arr_result');
 ajaxGet('/goget.php?type='+edit.reg.value, 'reg_result');
 </script>
```

But it only executes the last call. Why?

Javascript:

```
var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();

} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {

XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

function ajaxGet(ajaxLoadData, changeToID) {

if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {

    var obj = document.getElementById(changeToID);
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", ajaxLoadData);
    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status ==     200) {

        obj.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;

    }
}

    XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);

}
}
```

Comment: And what does the ajaxGet function look like ?

Comment: Probably some asynchronous issue, can we see `ajaxGet`?

Comment: How did this get a +1? You haven't posted enough code for anybody to debug. Please post `ajaxGet`.

Comment: Did you get any error messages in the console? Maybe the first call already causes an error and that's why the next calls will never get executed.

Comment: You'll have to place all the variables inside the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to have each call to `ajaxGet` create its own `XMLHttpRequest`.

An `XMLHttpRequest` can only handle 1 request at a time. And, since they'll be making the request asynchronously, they'll be processing in parallel rather than sequentially.

```
function ajaxGet(ajaxLoadData, changeToID) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(changeToID);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", ajaxLoadData);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            obj.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

Granted, browsers generally limit requests to only a few at a time (usually 2), queuing any additional. But your code shouldn't count on that.

---

Side note: Unless you need to support IE6 or older, you shouldn't need to fallback to `ActiveXObject`.

Comment: Thank you! I was using a function from an old website i created years ago. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `ajaxGet()` method to instantiate a new `XMLHttpRequest` object at every call. Since, you're using the same `XMLHttpRequest` every new request is overwriting the previous one.

Hence, you're getting the results returned by the last method call only.

```
function getXHRObj() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}

function ajaxGet(ajaxLoadData, changeToID) {
    var XMLHttpRequestObject = getXHRObj();
    var obj = document.getElementById(changeToID);
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", ajaxLoadData);
    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {
            obj.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
        }
    }
    XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
}
```